# What's the best way to navigate from between two screens in an App?

Tags: user-behavior, user-research, interface

***What's the best way to navigate from between two screens in an App?***

I'm writing an app which essentially consists of 2 screens of content, each displaying different type of news. I'm having a really hard time deciding how to navigate screen to screen.

1. Sliding Menu? I think it's a little overkill and users will feel like there's not much to the app.
2. Navigation bar at the bottom of the screen? Might look a little odd, cuz users are used to seeing 4-5 items on the bar
3. Any suggestions?

Comment: what's the context? Mobile? Desktop? What kind of news? How is the news formatted? Who is the audience?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your app is really just two screens of content, then you can try treating each screen as a pane in a horizontal carousel where you can **swipe between them**.  Take a look at the iOS weather app as an example.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Great idea! thx

Answer (score 0):

I will use something like Amazon kindle, just 2 buttons on the side, forward and back

Update:

Alright the idea was something like this:
You have a very simple application, 2 screen, therefore why don't you base on something very simple as the interface of the kindle. I know in this picture there a more buttons, but what I meant was this. Imagine you have a brochure in your hands, that is the feeling  the user should have. Simple things. Usually you hold the brochure with the right hand, but don't forget about the left-handed people. So the app would have two buttons to switch between screens, by the position of your thumbs. Look at the picture. The buttons would be of the size of you thumb finger tips, a bit bigger. Of course you can do it as a button or add to it the slide effect as "the correct answer suggested" like the iPhone weather forecast.

I didn't think I would have to give so many explanation for this simple idea. You scare me people (kidding).

[image]

Comment: What are the benefits of that pattern, from your point of view?

Comment: I is simple and if you put two buttons one on each side you can handle it with you thumbs like handling a book. This was my suggestion, it is simple as the ebook. I don't exactly the type of app he would like to do nor the device would run on. I supposed it was a mobile or pad.

Comment: When you say "Amazon kindler", do you mean the kindle, or is "kindler" an app?

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I'm talking about the device, the reader. Anyway, it was just an opinion nobody has to follow what I say. :)

Comment: @SnakeSanders You could edit your answer with more information, like the hint about this way of handling the problem resembles a physical book and turning its pages at the bottom on each side. Like this, your answer gives an opinion, but little insight.